# Why is my value not preserved in to the Runnable?

Tags: android, android-view, runnable

I have a routine which I use to set Text Views. It does some nominal processing of the names, filling in blanks, etc. Also, it runs on the UI Thread using View.Post. Here's the relevant portions of said function:

```
public void setValue(final String value)
{
    Log.v(TAG,"Name="+ mFieldName.getText()+" value="+value);
    //Log.v(TAG,unknown);
    mValue.post(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.v(TAG,"Start: Name="+ mFieldName.getText()+" value="+value);
            if (value==null)
                mValue.setText(R.string.loading);
            else
                mValue.setText(value);
            Log.v(TAG,"Posted: Name="+ mFieldName.getText()+" value="+mValue.getText());
        }   
    });
```

mValue and mFieldName are TextViews specified in other places. Notice the 3 Log statements. Here are 3 for the Name Accuracy:

```
10-27 22:27:49.491: V/OOP(19865): Name=Accuracy value=25.0 m
10-27 22:27:50.171: V/OOP(19865): Start: Name=Accuracy value=null
10-27 22:27:50.171: V/OOP(19865): Posted: Name=Accuracy value=Finding...
```

I'm having a very hard time understanding how the value could have changed at all during the process of creating the runnable. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think the above log is possible if you call the method `setValue` more than once (successively, eg. in a loop). Do you do that?

Comment: This is weird. I can only imagine this happening if you have your own `Runnable` class which has `value` as an instance variable - `static abstract class Runnable implements java.lang.Runnable { String value; }`. Can you check the imports?
`

Comment: That is strange. Do you use the name "value" anywhere else in your code (i.e., in a global variable)?

Comment: `value` is not used anywhere else. setValue is used by a bunch of classes (It's inherited by a bunch). It is at least remotely possible that it is called multiple times in different loops successively, I'm still working on tracking that down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like what was happening is that `setValue` was called multiple times without having been finished. I prevented that by checking for it, and adding a `boolean viewChangePending` class. I could probably have done this just as easily with a locking thread, but this seems to do the trick, so...

```
public void setValue(final String value)
{
    final String fieldName= new String((String) mFieldName.getText());
    Log.v(TAG,"Name="+ fieldName+" value="+value);
    //Log.v(TAG,unknown);
    try {
        while(viewChangePending)
                Thread.sleep(1);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    viewChangePending=true;
    mValue.post(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.v(TAG,"Start: Name="+ fieldName+" value="+value);
            if (value==null)
                mValue.setText(R.string.loading);
            else
                mValue.setText(value);
            Log.v(TAG,"Posted: Name="+ fieldName+" value="+mValue.getText());
            viewChangePending=false;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to show value or anything impact to UI, you should run theard RunOnUiThread.

Here is example:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
         //YOUR CODE HERE
    }
});
```